# creating a trigger for date_created and date modified

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

Could you please kindly assist

I have a table that i will be loading data into and on that table i have Date_Created and Date_Modified.
I have created a trigger to getdate for Date_Created and this should only apply for newly inserted data. however if a record is updated it should getdate for the modified_date and this should only apply when data is modified.

Below is the trigger I created. thanks

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TRGI_loadedDate_SAMPLE]'))
DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[TRGI_loadedDate_SAMPLE]
GO


CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TRGI_loadedDate_SAMPLE] ON [dbo].[SAMPLE_REG]
FOR UPDATE 
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @PK UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
        @DATE_CREATED DATE

SELECT @PK = SR.PK,
 @DATE_CREATED = GETDATE()--Get current datetime
FROM   SAMPLE_REG SR 
INNER JOIN INSERTED I 
ON   SR.PK = i.Pk

UPDATE SAMPLE_REG  --Update date modified
  SET  DATE_CREATED = @DATE_CREATED
WHERE PK=@PK
END
```

Comment: @marc_s Microsoft SQL Database

Comment: Your trigger has some major flaws in it. You need to realize that triggers fire once per statement, not once per row. The way you have coded your trigger it will not work correctly for multiple row statements. Also, this is the update trigger but you are setting the value for DATE_CREATED not DATE_MODIFIED. Drop the scalar variables and make your update set based (and the right column) and you will be good to go.

Comment: @SeanLange could you please explain your thinking behind "triggers fire once per statement, not once pew row"? As far as I know there are triggers that are for each row (most commonly used) which fire whenever a row is inserted/deleted/updated in a table

Comment: @ConsiderMe: SQL Server does ***not*** have `for each row` triggers. A trigger is always called **once per statement**, and if that statement happens to affect multiple rows, the `Inserted` and/or `Deleted` pseudo tables will contain **multiple rows** that you need to deal with properly

Comment: mar_s you are right the trigger fire once per statement and @SeanLange the trigger currently works fine for Date_Created, however I would like to add into the trigger the date_modiefed for any row that is updated instead of insert.

Comment: The point I was making that apparently got lost is you said you want to update the date modified but your code is NOT updating that column. It is updating the date created column. I would consider using two triggers. One for update and another for insert. You might even make the insert an instead of trigger so you can be 99.999% certain you get the date created set to the current datetime. I didn't say 100% because a trigger can always be disabled. In your update trigger rewrite your update as set based and it should be ok.

Comment: @marcs_s thanks for clarification, I was unaware of that (regarding SQL Server). Do you happen to know whether or not there is anything alike Postgres' TG_OP in SQL Server?